# How to marshal WCHAR* in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

I'm trying to pinvoke a [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323670(v=vs.85).aspx) that receives a couple of `WCHAR <paramName>[1]` parameters.

From what I've read in multiple places, in C/C++ you can't actually pass arrays to functions, instead they get converted to a pointer holding the first element of the array, which means that the array length becomes irrelevant and therefore `WCHAR <paramName>[1]` is the same as `WCHAR* <paramName>`.

So normally I'd declare this as a `StringBuilder` in C# and marshal it as `LPWStr`, but in this particular case that throws all sorts of errors.

Basically, the function above receives a [GET_VIRTUAL_DISK_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which in turn holds a union of some structs and other loose fields. And it is a couple of the structs in the union that receive a `WCHAR <paramName>[1]`.

When I try to marshal it as `LPWStr` and declare my field as `StringBuilder` or `string` I get the error `[...] contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.`

I've also tried declaring it as an `IntPtr` and then using `Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(<IntPtr>)` but I get an empty string.

My C# code with all the structs, enums etc:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Guid VirtualStorageTypeVendorMicrosoft = new Guid("EC984AEC-A0F9-47e9-901F-71415A66345B");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var handle = new VirtualDiskSafeHandle();
            var storageType = new VirtualStorageType
            {
                DeviceId = VirtualStorageDeviceType.Vhdx,
                VendorId = VirtualStorageTypeVendorMicrosoft
            };

            var parameters = new OpenVirtualDiskParameters
            {
                Version = OpenVirtualDiskVersion.Version2
            };

            var result = OpenVirtualDisk(ref storageType, "D:\\Test2.vhdx", VirtualDiskAccessMask.None, OpenVirtualDiskFlag.None,
                ref parameters, ref handle);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception((int) result);
            }

            var info = new GetVirtualDiskInfo {Version = GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion.PhysicalDisk};
            var infoSize = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(info);
            uint sizeUsed = 0;

            result = GetVirtualDiskInformation(handle, ref infoSize, ref info, ref sizeUsed);

            if (result != 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception((int) result);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"LogicalSizeSector = {info.Union.PhysicalDisk.LogicalSectorSize}");
            Console.WriteLine($"PhysicalSizeSector = {info.Union.PhysicalDisk.PhysicalSectorSize}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        [DllImport("virtdisk.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern uint OpenVirtualDisk(
            [In]        ref VirtualStorageType virtualStorageType,
            [In]            string path,
            [In]            VirtualDiskAccessMask virtualDiskAccessMask,
            [In]            OpenVirtualDiskFlag flags,
            [In]        ref OpenVirtualDiskParameters parameters,
            [In, Out]   ref VirtualDiskSafeHandle handle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(
            [In]            IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("virtdisk.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern uint GetVirtualDiskInformation(
            [In]            VirtualDiskSafeHandle virtualDiskHandle,
            [In, Out]   ref uint virtualDiskInfoSize,
            [In, Out]   ref GetVirtualDiskInfo virtualDiskInfo,
            [In, Out]   ref uint sizeUsed);

        [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand)]
        public class VirtualDiskSafeHandle : SafeHandle
        {
            public VirtualDiskSafeHandle() : base(IntPtr.Zero, true) { }

            public override bool IsInvalid => IsClosed || (handle == IntPtr.Zero);

            public bool IsOpen => !IsInvalid;

            protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
            {
                return CloseHandle(handle);
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return handle.ToString();
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct OpenVirtualDiskParameters
        {
            public OpenVirtualDiskVersion Version; //OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_VERSION
            public OpenVirtualDiskParametersUnion Union;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct OpenVirtualDiskParametersUnion
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public OpenVirtualDiskParametersVersion1 Version1;

            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public OpenVirtualDiskParametersVersion2 Version2;

            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public OpenVirtualDiskParametersVersion3 Version3;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct OpenVirtualDiskParametersVersion1
        {
            public uint RWDepth; //ULONG
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct OpenVirtualDiskParametersVersion2
        {
            public bool GetInfoOnly; //BOOL
            public bool ReadOnly; //BOOL
            public Guid ResiliencyGuid; //GUID 
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct OpenVirtualDiskParametersVersion3
        {
            public bool GetInfoOnly; //BOOL
            public bool ReadOnly; //BOOL
            public Guid ResiliencyGuid; //GUID 
            public Guid SnapshotId; //GUID
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct GetVirtualDiskInfo
        {
            public GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion Version; //GET_VIRTUAL_DISK_INFO_VERSION
            public GetVirtualDiskInfoUnion Union;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct GetVirtualDiskInfoUnion
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoSize Size;
            [FieldOffset(0)] public Guid Identifier; //GUID
            [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoParentLocation ParentLocation;
            [FieldOffset(0)] public Guid ParentIdentifier; //GUID
            [FieldOffset(0)] public uint ParentTimestamp; //ULONG
            [FieldOffset(0)] public VirtualStorageType VirtualStorageType; //VIRTUAL_STORAGE_TYPE
            [FieldOffset(0)] public uint ProviderSubtype; //ULONG
            [FieldOffset(0)] public bool Is4kAligned; //BOOL
            [FieldOffset(0)] public bool IsLoaded; //BOOL
            [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoPhysicalDisk PhysicalDisk;
            [FieldOffset(0)] public uint VhdPhysicalSectorSize; //ULONG
            [FieldOffset(0)] public ulong SmallestSafeVirtualSize; //ULONGLONG
            [FieldOffset(0)] public uint FragmentationPercentage; //ULONG
            [FieldOffset(0)] public Guid VirtualDiskId; //GUID
            [FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoChangeTrackingState ChangeTrackingState;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct GetVirtualDiskInfoSize
        {
            public ulong VirtualSize; //ULONGLONG
            public ulong PhysicalSize; //ULONGLONG
            public uint BlockSize; //ULONG
            public uint SectorSize; //ULONG
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct GetVirtualDiskInfoParentLocation
        {
            public bool ParentResolved; //BOOL
            public IntPtr ParentLocationBuffer; //WCHAR[1]
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct GetVirtualDiskInfoPhysicalDisk
        {
            public uint LogicalSectorSize; //ULONG
            public uint PhysicalSectorSize; //ULONG
            public bool IsRemote; //BOOL
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct GetVirtualDiskInfoChangeTrackingState
        {
            public bool Enabled; //BOOL
            public bool NewerChanges; //BOOL
            public IntPtr MostRecentId; //WCHAR[1]
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct VirtualStorageType
        {
            public VirtualStorageDeviceType DeviceId; //ULONG
            public Guid VendorId; //GUID
        }

        public enum GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion
        {
            Unspecified = 0,
            Size = 1,
            Identifier = 2,
            ParentLocation = 3,
            ParentIdentifier = 4,
            ParentTimestamp = 5,
            VirtualStorageType = 6,
            ProviderSubtype = 7,
            Is4KAligned = 8,
            PhysicalDisk = 9,
            VhdPhysicalSectorSize = 10,
            SmallestSafeVirtualSize = 11,
            Fragmentation = 12,
            IsLoaded = 13,
            VirtualDiskId = 14,
            ChangeTrackingState = 15
        }

        public enum VirtualStorageDeviceType
        {
            Unknown = 0,
            Iso = 1,
            Vhd = 2,
            Vhdx = 3,
            Vhdset = 4
        }

        public enum VirtualDiskAccessMask
        {
            None = 0x00000000,
            AttachRo = 0x00010000,
            AttachRw = 0x00020000,
            Detach = 0x00040000,
            GetInfo = 0x00080000,
            Create = 0x00100000,
            Metaops = 0x00200000,
            Read = 0x000d0000,
            All = 0x003f0000,
            Writable = 0x00320000
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum OpenVirtualDiskFlag
        {
            None = 0x00000000,
            NoParents = 0x00000001,
            BlankFile = 0x00000002,
            BootDrive = 0x00000004,
            CachedIo = 0x00000008,
            CustomDiffChain = 0x00000010,
            ParentCachedIo = 0x00000020,
            VhdsetFileOnly = 0x00000040
        }

        public enum OpenVirtualDiskVersion
        {
            Unspecified = 0,
            Version1 = 1,
            Version2 = 2,
            Version3 = 3,
        }
    }
}
```

Please comment out the line:

```
[FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoChangeTrackingState ChangeTrackingState;
```

Without that the struct results will be completely screwed up, still trying to figure out why.

Comment: As I was recently taught by @DavidHeffernan `WCHAR a[1]` is _not_ the same thing as `WCHAR* a`.  Arrays, in some cases, degenerate to pointers, but the data in the struct is inline.

Comment: That's fair enough, but then `WCHAR a[1]` would be an array with length of 1, and that's not enough to hold what this array supposedly holds: the path of the parent virtual disk.

Comment: Besides, there's a `out SizeUsed` param received by the function `GetVirtualDiskInformation` and the `SizeUsed` changes depending on where the parent virtual disk is, so I know it's returning more or less characters.

Comment: `WCHAR a[1]` is a flexible length array, the contents of which are actually inline with the data of the structure. The _address_ of the first element `&(a[0])` is equivalent to a string. See Also: [Why do some structures end with an array of size 1?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040826-00/?p=38043)

Comment: That's an incline array of length determined at runtime. You're going to need to marshal it manually.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how would I marshal this manually though? That's the bit I'm struggling with.

Comment: You need to get the address of the field and then use Marshal.PtrToStringUni. There's lots of ways to skin this depending on which info you need to extract. C++/CLI is much easier.....

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How would I get the address of the field? I've tried declaring it an IntPtr and using Marshal.PtrToStringUni, I get an empty string.

Comment: `Marshal.OffsetOf`

Comment: Think about it. A pointer contains an address. You want the address of the field. You will have to stop trying to marshal the struct automatically. Allocate a block of memory and pass its address to the function. Then marshal the fields you need manually.

Answer (score 2):

Marshal the struct from the function call as an `IntPtr`. You will need to use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` or another similar technique to get a block of unmanaged memory, since the Marshal isn't going to do it for you. You can then load the size member manually, or using `Marshal.StructureToPtr`.

From there use `Marshal.OffsetOf` to get the offset to the `Union` member. Once that's done use `Marshal.Read` and `Marshal.PtrToStringUni` to get at the data. For example with the Parent Location information:

```
IntPtr raw = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);

// This is the GetVirtualDiskInfo from your provided code.
GetVirtualDiskInfo info = new GetVirtualDiskInfo();
info.Version = GetVirtualDiskInfoVersion.ParentLocation;
Marshal.StructureToPtr(info, raw, true);

Class1.Test(raw); // Replace this with your call to the function,
                  // This is a call to a C++/CLI method I wrote to stuff data
                  // into the structure.

IntPtr offsetToUnion = Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(GetVirtualDiskInfo), "Union");
IntPtr data = raw + offsetToUnion.ToInt32();

bool parentResolved = Marshal.ReadInt32(data) != 0;
string parentLocationBuffer = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data + 4);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(raw); // Don't forget this!
```

Here's the method in the C++/CLI that loads the data for testing:

```
static void Test(IntPtr ptr)
{
    GET_VIRTUAL_DISK_INFO* info = (GET_VIRTUAL_DISK_INFO*)ptr.ToPointer();
    info->ParentLocation.ParentResolved = TRUE;
    memcpy(info->ParentLocation.ParentLocationBuffer, L"123456789", 20);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a clearer example where you also use the `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, `Marshal.StructureToPtr` and how the `Union` would be declared instead? I tried it on my own but still failing badly.

Comment: Added some code to demo the first paragraph, and the testing code used to validate it.

Comment: Thank you for that, but I'm still not getting it to work. Could you also post what your `GetVirtualDiskInfo` struct looks like, as well as the `GetVirtualDiskInfoParentLocation` struct?

Comment: I literally copied everything below the safe handle from your pastebin, and changed nothing.

Comment: So the Union remained the same with `[FieldOffset(0)] public GetVirtualDiskInfoParentLocation ParentLocation;` and the `GetVirtualDiskInfoParentLocation` struct as bool and IntPtr respectively? Can't get it to work that way. It returns false and null string respectively. I know for a fact the disk I'm using is a differencing disk so it has a parent and should return true (it returned true with the code I had at first for example)

Comment: You can't access the structure members directly. They will have meaningless data.

Comment: I understand that, but this is still not working for me and I think the problem is the Union.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114424/discussion-between-cogumel0-and-theb).